# Is there a way to get currently active wifi network card interface from a file in the fs - instead of via running commands such as iwconfig?

Tags: wifi

I know there are several ways to obtain the currently active network card interface by running different tools, one of them being `iwconfig`

I am after a way to achieve the same - but by accessing linux's file system only - if possible. I have a .NET app that already runs different processes to obtain different data - I need to minimize these external processes as much as possible.

Comment: On systems with multiple “active” interfaces, which one do you want? The interface providing the default route, or all of them?

Comment: @StephenKitt: a good point I did not take into consideration... for my needs, the first active suffices.

Comment: @StephenKitt: how do I figure out, when multiple active interfaces are supported, which is the wifi one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information can be obtained from:

```
cat /sys/class/net/$IFACE/operstate
```

The results is `up` or `down`

To list all interfaces names:

```
ls /sys/class/net
```

To check if it is a wireless card or not:

```
[[ -d "/sys/class/net/$IFACE/wireless" ]] && echo "WiFi card"
```

[Documentation for /proc/sys/net/](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/net.html)

[kernel archives](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-net)

Comment: Where in the kernel documentation can I sort out this out by myself, I mean, figuring out where in the file system this or that piece of information is written to, if it is ?

Comment: I noticed this solution does not check whether or not the net device with `operstate` equaling `up` - is a wireless card or not. Do you know how to figure that out as well somewhere in the file system ?

Comment: @Veverke see my edit please.

Comment: Thanks a lot, would give more upvotes were it possible!

Answer (score 2):

Adding to GAD3R's answer, just in case someone needs the script to automate what the answer recommends doing (a snippet I have written for that purpose):

```
#!/bin/bash
function getFirstActiveNIC()
{
    interfaces="/sys/class/net/*"
    for interface in ${interfaces};
        do 
            if [ $(cat "${interface}/operstate") = "up" ];
            then
                echo "$(basename ${interface})"
            fi
    done
}
```

Comment: [Stephen Kitt's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/678065/433212) more elegant answer.