# How to search over symbolink links for the existence of a file?

Tags: shell-script, grep, find, symlink

As a follow up on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/677795/433212) question, I am trying to determine which command/sequence of commands can give me which of the network interfaces listed under `/sys/class/net` is the wireless one - by searching for the one(s) where a symbolic link (again) named `wireless` is present.

1. The closest I could get is using `ls -LR | grep wireless`, though I would like to stop at the first match - tried using `-m 1`, piping to `head -1` but then I lose the file path of where the match was found, and this is actually what I am after, the match itself is useless. Did not manage to sort this out (tried adding -`H` along with `-m 1`, no deal).
2. In addition, why `find /sys/class/net -type l` alone does not achieve this? (using `sudo` gives me the same results, so it is not an issue of those links not being visible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can ask the shell to find it for you with a glob, *e.g.*

   ```
   echo /sys/class/net/*/wireless
   ```

   The behaviour when *no* wireless interface exists varies depending on your shell and its globbing configuration options.
2. `find` doesn’t follow symlinks by default; adding `-L` will change this, but then you’ll see why it doesn’t follow symlinks by default:

   ```
   find -L /sys/class/net -name wireless
   ```

   (the symlinks introduce loops).

You can write your complete check as

```
for ifc in /sys/class/net/*; do
    if [ "$(cat ${ifc}/operstate)" = "up" ] && [ -d "${ifc}/wireless" ]; then
        echo "${ifc##*/}"
    fi
done
```